# Getting ORC file format error "It doesn't match the specified format" in Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql

I am trying to write data to hive table in ORC format and I am getting following error.

```
Job failed with message [pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: The format of the existing table dbname.tablename is `HiveFileFormat`. It doesn't match the specified format `OrcDataSourceV2`.].
```

Following is hive write statement.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.partitionBy("date").mode('append').format('orc').saveAsTable(
'dbname.tablename'.format(dbname=destination_database))
```

I am not sure what is causing the issue but it is throwing above mentioned error.  what is the purpose of format after tablename?

Thanks for your help and really appreciate.

Thanks,Bab